# How to jump-to-todays-date onOpen for a spreadsheet with multiple tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a large team of people that access one spreadsheet.  Each person has a tab with a column of dates (Column C), and they enter information received for each date.  I'd like EACH sheet to jump to the current date upon opening their tab.  The script below works, but only for the first tab/sheet, and must be manually run for all other tabs, which is not worth the trouble. How can I fix this so that it runs on every tab once it's opened?

```
function onOpen() {
 var menu = [{name: "Jump to today's date", functionName: "jumpToDate"}];
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);
 jumpToDate();
}

function jumpToDate() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange("C:C");
 var values = range.getValues();  
 var day = 24*3600*1000;  
 var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);  
 var ssdate; 
 for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
   try {
     ssdate = values[i][0].getTime()/day;
   }
   catch(e) {
   }
   if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today) {
     sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(i,0,1,1));
     break;
   }    
 }
}
```

Comment: what does "large" mean in this case ? and also are you working with a business/education google account inside a domain ? or a normal gmail account ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no event trigger selecting sheet in [[image]google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)

But each tab has unique link. If each user has own tab, they might save the link to personal tad, and script will work when Spreadsheet is open, because of this line:

`var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();`

Comment: I think you mean there is no event *trigger* selecting sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect the sheet selection from script but you can change the way users are selecting the active sheet in a spreadsheet.
Using a sidebar it can be more user friendly than the usual selection mode, especially when you have many sheets.

The code below is a simplified version of a sidebar tool I use a lot. I removed all the unnecessary items (at least I hope so!) and integrated your code to jump to the current date.

It uses JQUERY because it's part of a much bigger script where I use it a lot but I admit it's not very useful in this simple script... I was just  too lazy to remove it :)

The whole code is quite long but is quite simple to understand.
You can also start from a copy of [this public copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IhubJ-wNeFffCPA4uaPXG0K_J9bI6Q_Is_tQxQI6YRE/edit?usp=sharing).

[image]

code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu("Authorize")
  .addItem('Authorize script', 'authorize')
  .addToUi();
  showSidebar();
}

function authorize(){
  showSidebar();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Sidebar')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('Page selection');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}


function createList(){
  var ssProfs_envois = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var list = [];
  var sh, sheetName;
  for(var s=0;s<ssProfs_envois.getNumSheets();s++){
    sh = ssProfs_envois.getSheets()[s];
    sheetName = sh.getName();
    list.push(sheetName);
  }
  var message = ''; 
  var color;
  message+= '<table style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:arial,sans;font-size:9pt;" border = 1 >';
  message+='<tr valign="top" cellpadding=5>'
  for(var n=0;n<list.length;n++){
      color="#000"
    message+='<tr><td align="center">&nbsp'+(n+1)+'&nbsp</td><td>'+
      '<input type="button" id="button'+n+'" value="'+list[n]+'" style="color:'+color+'; width:200px;font-size:10pt;white-space:normal;" onclick="selectSheet(\''+n+'\')"/></td></tr>';
  }
  message+='</table>';
  return message;
}

function showSheetGS(sheetNumber){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[sheetNumber].activate();
  jumpToDate(sheet);
}

function jumpToDate(sheet) {
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A");
  var values = range.getValues();  
  var day = 24*3600*1000;  
  var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);  
  var ssdate; 
  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    try {
      ssdate = values[i][0].getTime()/day;
    }
    catch(e) {
    }
    if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today) {
      sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(i,0,1,1));
      break;
    }    
  }
}
```

Sidebar.html

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>

<!-- Below is the HTML code that defines the sidebar element structure. -->
<div class="sidebar branding-below">
<!-- The div-table class is used to make a group of divs behave like a table. -->
<h3>Available tabs,<br><span style="color:#070"> Green typeface = </span>sheet already selected</h3>
  <div id="sidebarList">
  <br><br><br>...wait a moment,<br>list is being created.
  <p>If nothing happens then please authorize the script using the menu.</p> 
  </div>

<!-- Enter sidebar bottom-branding below. -->
  <div class="sidebar bottom">
  <img alt="Add-on logo" class="logo" width="25"
      src="http://insas.cluster006.ovh.net/serge/apps-script_2x.png">
  <span class="gray branding-text">Sheet Select tool<br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp© SG 2017</span>
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('SidebarJavaScript').getContent(); ?>
```

SidebarJavaScript.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Run initializations on sidebar load.
   */
populateEncodeLocal();

function populateEncodeLocal(){
   //console.log('populateEncode');
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateList).createList();
}

function selectSheet(sheetNumber){
  console.log(sheetNumber);
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showSheet(sheetNumber)).showSheetGS(sheetNumber);
}
function showSheet(n){
  console.log("showSheet"+n);
  $('#button'+n).css('font-size','14pt').css('color','#070');
}

function populateList(data){
   //console.log(data);
   $('#sidebarList').html(data);
}
</script>
```

Stylesheet.html

```
<!-- This CSS package applies Google styling; it should always be included. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<style>

html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#sidebarList {
  width:270px;
  height:600px;
  overflow:auto;
  }

input[type="button"] {
    height: 23px;
    width: 270px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.branding-below {
  bottom: 3px;
  top: 0px;
  padding-left:0px;
}

.branding-text {
  left: 7px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}

.logo {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.width-100 {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing : border-box;‌
  -moz-box-sizing : border-box;
}

#sidebar-value-block,
#dialog-elements {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-color: #eee;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#sidebar-button-bar,
#dialog-button-bar {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.div-table{
  display:table;
  width:280px;
  height:500px;
  background-color:#eee;
  border:1px solid  #666666;*/
  border-spacing:2px;
  font-size:8,5pt;
}
.div-table-row{
  display:table-row;
  width:auto;
  clear:both;
}
.div-table-td, .div-table-th {
  display:table-cell;         
  width:auto;   
  background-color:rgb(230, 230, 230);  
  padding-left:4px;
  padding-right:4px;
}
.div-table-th {
  /*float:left;*/
  font-weight: bold;
}
.div-table-td {
  /*float:right;*/
}
div.ui-datepicker{
padding:0px;
font-size:90%;
 width: 250px;
 heigth: 90px;
  }

th {
  border-bottom: 0px solid #acacac;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 1px 1px 0;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  border-bottom: 0px solid #ebebeb;
  padding: 1px 0;
}


}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of possible, but slow.

The idea is call jumpToDate to all sheets, one by one, with trigger onOpen(). However, Google Sheets never renders all sheets at the same time when you open a single sheet, but only the one you opened and, it seems, the most frequently opened ones. When you click an "unpopular" sheet tab, your browser needs to render it, which took 500 milliseconds in my tests on a simple sheet. It may take more time in your larger spreadsheet.

Here is how I adapted your code to answer your question:

```js
function jumpToDate() {
  /* optional:*/ /*var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert('Today', 'To scroll to today, please click yes.', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if(response == "NO"){return}; */
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets(); // this now gets all the sheets
  var numSheets = ss.getNumSheets(); // gets number of sheets
  
  var day = 24*3600*1000;  
  var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);   
  var range;
  var values;  
  var ssdate; 
  
  for (h = 0; h < numSheets; h++) {
    
    range = sheet[h].getRange("C:C"); // note the [h]
    ss.setActiveSheet(sheet[h]);
    Utilities.sleep(500); // without this line, it runs much faster but some sheets don't load.
                          // I recommend that you play around and increase/decrease the 500 number
                    
    values = range.getValues(); 
    
    for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
      try {
        ssdate = values[i][0].getTime()/day;
      }
      catch(e) {
      }
      if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today) {
        sheet[h].setActiveRange(range.offset(i,0,1,1)); // note the [h]
        break;
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

It's likely that this option is too slow for your needs, so I would recommend that we approach the problem differently. Does the page really need to show all those rows that we don't edit everyday? Do we even read them often? If not, we could hide the rows we that don't use as much. It can be done using the [hideRows(rowIndex, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowsrowindex-numrows) method.

1. Creating function hideOld() that hides all rows before today
2. Customizing hideOld() to hide rows before (today - 10 days)
3. Adding a trigger that runs hideOld() at 3:00 AM daily.

Comment: I tried your first solution but also found it too slow. I like your second suggestion, good idea if it meets the requirement in this case !